# The secret of Fuzz?

Tags: electric-guitar, effects-pedal, electric-bass-guitar

I was chatting with a fellow bass player about my new line-up of effects pedals which my last gig enabled/required, and I commented that I had a "black rat fuzz" and when she looked at it she said, "oh, it's a rat clone! That's kinda more of a distortion."

Intrigued I investigated the subject of Fuzz, and apparently it all began with a happy accident in the recording of a Country Song called *Don't Worry.* Where the channel on the recording console had *something gone bad* in it.

[Marty Robbins, *Don't Worry*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sB7H6pT3DW4)

This very same broken console circuit was used in the followup hit, *The Fuzz*.

[Grady Martin, *The Fuzz*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vp3YHnDPRv0)

Therefore, *every* Fuzz box is a clone of that original effect. Are there any pedals or units which are *directly* copied from the actual breakage of that original circuit? What happened in the change from 1 Fuzz to many Fuzzes? Who made the first clone and how did they do it?

Comment: Funny. I always thought the ProCo Rat was firmly in the fuzz category.

Comment: The most common fuzz pedal that I've seen people using is the Big Muff.  I have a kind of copy of that called a Swollen Pickle that I use in my bass rig.  It's a little overpowering for my setup and the bands I play in, so it's gone underused.  Fuzz tends to be a very strong distortion and can remove a lot of the pitch clarity and attack characteristics.  I got a cool pedal that allows me to create an effects loop within my pedal board and mix the wet/dry signals, so I've been able to utilize the pedal more now with that (that pedal is the X Blender, super cool).

Comment: Yep, I've rigged up something similar with an aby box and a mixer. 1/2 distorted signal + 1/2 dry gives back all the missing punch and thump. I split after the overdrive so both get a little drive.

Answer (score 6):

https://thehub.musiciansfriend.com/tech-tips/how-electric-guitars-got-their-fuzz-on describes that incident as follows:

> Another documented early fuzz bass sound also grew out of a
>   malfunction. During a 1960 Nashville recording session with
>   country-pop singer Marty Robbins, a transformer blew in the
>   tube-driven Langevin recording console, giving bassist Grady Martin a
>   thick layer of hair on his bassline for the forgettable ballad, “Don’t
>   Worry.” Engineer Glenn Snoddy was intrigued by the accidental effect
>   and set about trying to replicate it without disabling a circuit in
>   his mixing desk. Snoddy tinkered with solid-state circuits exploiting
>   the germanium transistor’s tendency to spew out strange, distorted
>   tones.
>
> In 1962 Snoddy sold his circuit design to Gibson who then began
>   producing what is commonly thought to be the first commercially
>   available effects pedal, the Maestro FZ1-A Fuzz Tone...

It sounds to me like the Maestro Fuzz Tone is the closest thing there is to something directly inspired by that particular console.

Answer (score 1):

I'm familiar with the track you mention on Don't Worry, and it did precede the story I heard about the Fuzz pedal. The story I was told was that Vox developed the Fuzz pedal in an attempt to make a guitar sound like a Sax, and was shown to Keith Richard at the time of the recording sessions for " I can't get no Satisfaction". I heard that many loudspeakers were shredded in an attempt to duplicate that sound by budding guitar players back in the mid-sixties. I suppose both stories could be true, but I can't say for sure.

Comment: From my research, this is partly true. The Tone Bender was marketed as a way to make the guitar sound like a horn or a cello. Keith used it for a temp track, expecting a real sax player to be hired later. The Tone Bender itself was a clone of the Maestro Fuzz. Maybe the first clone pedal.

Comment: I stand corrected.